# Bit Flags - What am I missing?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

a simple code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    lit.Text += "<br/>now.DayOfWeek: " + now.DayOfWeek.ToString();

    // weekdays (Saturday is not included)
    DayOfWeek runningDays = DayOfWeek.Monday | DayOfWeek.Tuesday | DayOfWeek.Wednesday | DayOfWeek.Thursday | DayOfWeek.Friday;

    lit.Text += "<br/>" + runningDays.HasFlag(now.DayOfWeek);
    lit.Text += "<br/>" + runningDays.HasAny(now.DayOfWeek);
    lit.Text += "<br/>" + ((runningDays & now.DayOfWeek) != 0);

    // weekend (Saturday is in a weekend)
    runningDays = DayOfWeek.Saturday | DayOfWeek.Sunday;

    lit.Text += "<br/>" + runningDays.HasFlag(now.DayOfWeek);
    lit.Text += "<br/>" + runningDays.HasAny(now.DayOfWeek);
    lit.Text += "<br/>" + ((runningDays & now.DayOfWeek) != 0);
}
```

A helper:

```
public static bool HasExactly(this DayOfWeek x, DayOfWeek y) { return x == y; }
public static bool HasAny(this DayOfWeek x, DayOfWeek y) { return 0 != (x & y); }
public static bool HasAll(this DayOfWeek x, DayOfWeek y) { return y == (x & y); }
```

today's output (Saturday)

```
now.DayOfWeek: Saturday
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

But the output should be like:

```
now.DayOfWeek: Saturday
False
False
False
True
True
True
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Days of week are not bit flags. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx

> The value of the constants in the
>   DayOfWeek enumeration ranges from
>   DayOfWeek.Sunday to
>   DayOfWeek.Saturday. If cast to an
>   integer, its value ranges from zero
>   (which indicates DayOfWeek.Sunday) to
>   six (which indicates
>   DayOfWeek.Saturday).

Comment: I knew I was been stupid :( Thank you for pointing me out the docs ... I keep forgetting that they are an important part of the developer role... but I really did assume that DayOfWeek was a Flag Enum :o(

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post but just in case - a neat syntax to do flags enums is

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    None = 1 << 0,
    Monday = 1 << 1,
    Tuesday = 1 << 2,
    Wednesday = 1 << 3,
    Thursday = 1 << 4,
    Friday = 1 << 5,
    Saturday = 1 << 6,
    Sunday = 1 << 7
}
```

You would need None to indicate nothing was selected. Such an enum allows you to indicate multiple days, for example:

```
var selectedDays = DaysOfWeek.Tuesday | DaysOfWeek.Friday;
```

No comment needed hopefully. And in order to "decode" the value:

```
public bool IsDayOfWeekSelected(DaysOfWeek which, DaysOfWeek selection)
{
    return selection & which == which;
}
```

And this then allows us to call:

```
var isTuesday = IsDayOfWeekSelected(DaysOfWeek.Tuesday, selectedDays); // => true
var isWednesday = IsDayOfWeekSelected(DaysOfWeek.Wednesday, selectedDays); // => false
var isFriday = IsDayOfWeekSelected(DaysOfWeek.Friday, selectedDays); // => true
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I would go with Extension Method, something like: `public static bool IsDayOfWeekSelected(this DaysOfWeek selectedDays, DaysOfWeek which) { return selection & which == which; }` then you could easily just do: `selectedDays.IsDayOfWeekSelected(DaysOfWeek.Tuesday);` ;o)

Comment: Good point. They you don't have to stuff it into a Utility class :)

Comment: I'd always default `None` to 0, and you can also use `Sunday = 1 << DayOfWeek.Sunday` etc to map to the .NET `DayOfWeek`

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own DayOfWeek enum if you need to use it like flags:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyDayOfWeek { Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, Tuesday = 4, ... , Saturday = 64 };
```

Comment: yes, I ended up doing that :) but I did assume wrongly that DayOfWeek was a Flag Enum ... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

DayOfWeek has sequential numbers.

Use a `List<DayOfWeek>`.

Go to definition shows:

```
// Summary:
//     Specifies the day of the week.
[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Sunday.
    Sunday = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Monday.
    Monday = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Tuesday.
    Tuesday = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Wednesday.
    Wednesday = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Thursday.
    Thursday = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Friday.
    Friday = 5,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Saturday.
    Saturday = 6,
}
```

Comment: err... then you can't apply bit operators where in this example are the best to be used!

Comment: Nope. But best may be from a premature optimization performance point of view, not readability point of view. List.Contains, etc are easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The `DayOfWeek` enumeration was designed to represent a single day of the week, not a set of days.

You don't get a compiler error for using `&` because enums are integers, but the operator doesn't do what you expect (unless you happen to only schedule events on Mondays, Tuesdays, or Thursdays).

If you want a bit flag, then declare a bit flag type, like Ray suggested.

Comment: yep... my mistake was assuming that DayofWeek was a bit flag type ... it never occur me any other way ... dumb me :-(